# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5200 (apt)

Tags: apt, sudo, lock

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5200 (apt)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: If you're like me, I'd check for another window on another workspace where you started a upgrade/install etc, and it got to a point where it's asking for permission to continue etc..  Answer & finish that and it resolves itself (it can also be you were just unlucky and the system happened to be checking for upgrades, meaning after a few mins that will have been resolved by itself anyway).

Comment: I figured it out all you have to do is mount os folder on desktop

Answer (score 9):

Open your terminal and type:

```
ps -aux | grep -iE "apt"
```

It will show the id of the process running `apt`.  Kill it with:

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

You could also kill all processes using `apt` with:

```
sudo killall apt apt-get
```

If these commands don't work, you can also remove the files using `rm`:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*
```

**NOTE:**  Be careful with those commands.  You could possibly end up with a broken system if you are careless.

Reconfigure the packages, and update:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks , but all i did was mount the folder on desktop.. Fixed

Comment: Why would those commands result in a broken system?